# Вставить или заменить MySQL

Tags: sqlite, sql, mysql

В `sqlite` можно построить такой запрос

```
insert OR REPLACE into items (field) values (field)
```

однако в `MySQL` он работать не будет. Есть ли какой либо аналог для `MySQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REPLACE INTO items ( field1, field2 ) VALUES ( value1, value2 )
```

`REPLACE` -- работает на основе уникальных ключей. грубо говоря если он во время инсерта встречает `DUPLICATE` то его апдейтит.

По правам доступа. нужно иметь права и на `DELETE`  и на `INSERT`, чтобы выполнять реплейс